# Typescript save interface in parent interface

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to write an Angular2 application which receives messages via WebSocket.
The messages have a different content but always contains a message identifier.
That's why I'd like to use a child-parent-architecture. But the compiler gives me an error when I try to run the following code.
Thank you in advance.

> Typescript code

```
export interface Message {
    id: String
}

export interface PlayerData extends Message {
    age: String
}

export interface ScoreInfo extends Message {
    tBest: number,
    tPlayer: number
}

@Injectable()
export class GameCommunicationService {
    public messages: Subject<Message>;
    constructor(wsService: WebsocketService) {
        this.messages = <Subject<Message>>wsService
            .connect(CHAT_URL)
            .map((response: MessageEvent): Message => {
                let data = JSON.parse(response.data);
                if (data.id == 12) {
                    return {
                        id: data.id,
                        age: data.age
                    }
                } else if (data.id == 13) {
                    return {
                        id: data.id,
                        tBest: data.tBest,
                        tPlayer: data.tPlayer
                    }
                } else {
                    return {
                        id: data.id
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Error:

```
ERROR in D:/angular/src/app/game-communication.service.ts (57,7): Type '{   code: any; age: any; }' is not assignable to type 'Message'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'age' does not exist in type 'Message'.

ERROR in D:/angular/src/app/game-communication.service.ts (57,15): Cannot find name 'age'.

ERROR in D:/angular/src/app/game-communication.service.ts (57,7): Type '{ code: any; age: any; }' is not assignable to type 'Message'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'age' does not exist in type 'Message'.

ERROR in D:/angular/src/app/game-communication.service.ts (57,15): Cannot find name 'age'.
```

....

Comment: Which error? Can you post it?

Comment: here `map((response: MessageEvent): Message => {` , you are returning 
 type `Message` Interface. And `Message` interface does not contain `age` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
export interface Message {
    id: String
}
export interface PlayerData extends Message {
    age: String
}
export interface ScoreInfo extends Message {
    tBest: number,
    tPlayer: number
}
@Injectable()
export class GameCommunicationService {
    public messages: Subject<any>;
    constructor(wsService: WebsocketService) {
        this.messages = <Subject<any>>wsService
            .connect(CHAT_URL)
            .map((response: MessageEvent): any => {
                let data = JSON.parse(response.data);
                if (data.id == 12) {
                    return {
                        id: data.id,
                        age: data.age
                    }
                } else if (data.id == 13) {
                    return {
                        id: data.id,
                        tBest: data.tBest,
                        tPlayer: data.tPlayer
                    }
                } else {
                    return {
                        id: data.id
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

> You are using three different interfaces, so make use of generic type any instead of specific Subject of Message Interface.

[Polymorphism in Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass them to not required by using `?` like this

```
export interface PlayerData extends Message {
    age?: String
}

export interface ScoreInfo extends Message {
    tBest?: number,
    tPlayer?: number
}
```

And return a Intersection type like this:

```
this.messages = <Subject<Message>>wsService
            .connect(CHAT_URL)
            .map((response: MessageEvent): PlayerData & ScoreInfo  => {
                let data = JSON.parse(response.data);
                if (data.id == 12) {
                    return {
                        id: data.id,
                        age: data.age
                    }
                } else if (data.id == 13) {
                    return {
                        id: data.id,
                        tBest: data.tBest,
                        tPlayer: data.tPlayer
                    }
                } else {
                    return {
                        id: data.id
                    }
                }
            });
```